# Is it possible to import Unity games to Objectvie C apps?

Tags: objective-c

I'm planning to make a health and medical application for my seminar using objective C. But my professor asked me if I can somehow make a game with unity and put them into my app.

Is it possible to put my Unity game into the app written in Objective C?

Comment: Like embed a Unity game into your iOS app?

Comment: Please read the description of the [unity] tag (and update your question appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated question because it's one where the answer is mostly no, but kind of yes. Under certain conditions something like this is possible, for instance, you'd either need:

- Both applications to be open source (then you can just merge the two projects and combine them using code).
- One of the applications to be compatible with an emulator that is open source and works with Unity iOS apps.

Let me know if you'd like me to expand on any of these points. This is a pretty complicated topic. In short, unless you already knew the answer to this question, the answer is very likely no.